# Sort concatenated string in Jquery array

Tags: jquery, arrays

```
[{ "Id":"1", "Name":"Java_1" }, { "Id":"2", "Name":"MS_Java_1" }, { "Id":"3", "Name":"Java_2" }, { "Id":"4", "Name":"MS_Java_10" }, { "Id":"", "Name":"MS_Java_2" } ]
```

I want to sort this array based on Name in the below manner: Name(Order by Ascending)_Number(order by Ascending)

```
[{ "Id":"1", "Name":"Java_1" }, { "Id":"3", "Name":"Java_2" },{ "Id":"2", "Name":"MS_Java_1" }, { "Id":"", "Name":"MS_Java_2",  { "Id":"4", "Name":"MS_Java_10" }} ]
```

Comment: How did you try to sort the array, and where did you get stuck on?

Comment: hint: `a.Name.match(/^(.+)_(\d+)$/)`